# How to set sensors with latitude longitude location inputs in chrome using Protractor?

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

As I see, there is an option in `Selenium Webdriver` for sensor location settings through Chrome Debugging Protocol command; however, I couldn't find the relevant methods in `Protractor` tool.

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd(...)
```

[image]

Is there any Protractor implementation to set custom location coordinates in Chrome browser?

Comment: check this list https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ if it has a parameter for that

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov I checked it before; couldn't find there

Comment: then unlikely it can be done, unless manually